# Where are packages downloaded by "apt-get download" stored?

Tags: apt

I want to know the storage location of `apt-get download` command in Ubuntu.

Comment: file stores in the current directory itself(not in anyother places). And this question is not a dupe. Op clearly mentioned where packages are stored while i download it using `apt-get download`

Answer (score 5):

If you are just downloading using `apt-get` the file is stored in the current directory.

From `apt-get --help`

```
download - Download the binary package into the current directory
```

Comment: As of June 2021, this is no longer true (on Debian 10): Archives now get downloaded to /var/cache/apt/archives, as correctly indicated in on of these answers.

Answer (score 3):

The packages are stored under:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Comment: He's asking about the `download` command, which downloads in the current directory always.

Comment: No, not true anymore. As of 2021, this answer is the correct one. Your comment is incorrect.

Comment: not true - year 2023 . ubuntu 22 . the package go to *current folder*